# Issue with size limit (limit of 262144 bytes) from bot while displaying adaptive card with large choice list (in botframework)

Tags: node.js, adaptive-cards, botframework

My team is working on a chatbot with Microsoft bot framework, as a requirement we need to show a dynamic choice list according to what the users select. For this we are hitting an API to fetch the custom response. Please find below an example of the response.

```
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "val": {
                    "Field1": "Hello World"
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": [
                        {
                            "href": "API_URL_FOR_THIS_OPTION"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "val": {
                    "Field1": "Hi World"
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": [
                        {
                            "href": "API_URL_FOR_THIS_OPTION"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
    ],
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "MAIN_API_URL"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here, **the number of options to be shown in the dynamic choice list will be equal to the length of the items array**. The following code is used to convert this response into choices array compatible with adaptive cards

```
        var arr1=[]
        for(var i=0; i<resp.body.items.length;i++)
        {
          arr1.push(resp.body.items[i].values["Field1"])
        }
        var choice_arr_new=[];
        for(var j = 0; j<arr1.length; j++)
        {
            var dictionry={};
                dictionry['title'] = arr[j];
                dictionry['value'] = arr[j];
                choice_arr_new.push(dictionry);               
        }
```

It works well but **I am encountering a size limit of about 250 Kb** as the api response has **items.length of more than 3000 for some cases**. And hence, I receive the following **Error: The request content length exceeded limit of 262144 bytes**, while trying to pass the choice array to the Adaptive card

**Questions:-**

1. Is there any way to increase the size limit to accommodate large ***choices*** array for
   adaptive card?
2. Is there any alternative way to display the list within Bot Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to use cards, you will have to split your choices into multiple sets and distribute them across separate cards.

If you're using a flat list of choices then you may have to display many cards at once, and it would be a good idea to use carousels for that. You can use multiple activities to display multiple carousels. If you're interested in having a library that can disable multiple activities for you when a card in one of them is clicked, you may want to voice your support for my upcoming cards library: https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/issues/137

If you can categorize your choices, perhaps even just by the first letter of the title, then you may want to have the user select a category first and then select the actual choice from the smaller set within that category.

If you want to display each choice as a button, you could just use regular Bot Framework cards instead of Adaptive Cards. If you've ever tried a Web Chat sample then you may have noticed that [MockBot](https://microsoft.github.io/BotFramework-WebChat/01.getting-started/a.full-bundle/) displays its menu as a long list of cards with buttons. You could supposedly use suggested actions as well but it's generally not a good idea to display that many suggested actions at once.

Finally, you could just display all your choices as a numbered list so that the user could enter their choice as text.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed and perfect explanation, this is exactly what I was looking for