# How can we have more than 3000 values inside Input.ChoiceSet of adaptive cards?

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

Actually i am having 9000 values of data in which we need to be in dropdown of adaptivecards. But Input.choiceset is not showing >3000 values in it. can anyone suggest me what to do in this case??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with size limit (limit of 262144 bytes) from bot while displaying adaptive card with large choice list (in botframework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64755946/issue-with-size-limit-limit-of-262144-bytes-from-bot-while-displaying-adaptive)

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Inpu.Choiceset is limited. There are plans for dynamic dropdowns which would allow you to return your values from the backend including search options.

Having over 9000 values in the choice set would get you quickly to a lot of limits in Cards and would make the choiceset literarily unusable.

Currently there is no way to properly get that many values in a card.

Heres the request that would help you out once implemented, you can upvote it: https://portal.productboard.com/adaptivecards/1-adaptive-cards-features/c/15-input-choiceset-auto-complete?utm_medium=social&utm_source=portal_share

Comment: Yeah, thankyou I got it. Is there any workaround for this. And I have tried Input.Choiceset as searchable dropdown by using select2 plugin in which it worked for me only backlog is the limited values...

Comment: Don't know if there's any workaround, sorry. I never tried this as honestly i really think having that many choices makes the card unusable. So i never tried it myself.